# Jar Error while running mvn clean install

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, business-process-management

I am getting following errors while running mvn clean install in my project folder.Can anybody help me solve this issue.?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war- 
plugin:2.4:war (basic-deployment-war) on project rnd_web: Failed to 
copy file for artifact [bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile].

D:\path to\bcprov-jdk14-138.jar (The process cannot access the file because 
it is being used by another process)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you checked whether the file is used by another process? Have you restarted your Windows?

Comment: yes I have restarted windows and then check this but the same response occured

Comment: Have you tried to copy paste jar at different location ?